# React-Native Router Flux with Netwoking and Sceenchooser

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have a problem. 
My App work right now but not like how I want.

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: true,

  };
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({ data: json.movies });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  .finally(() => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  });
}

render() {
const { data, isLoading } = this.state;
const goToPageTwo = () => Actions.sw({text: 'Hello World!'});
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
    {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Actions.hp({text: item.id})  }}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        )}
      />
    )}
  </View>
  );
 }
};
```

index.js / Route.js in my case sm.js

```
import app from './App';
import sw from './StarWars'
import bttf from './BacktotheFuture'
import hP from './handlePage';
import tM from './theMatrix';
import iN from './Inception';

const SceneManager = () => (
<Router>
    <Scene>
    <Scene key='home'
                component={app}
                title='BTour'
                initial
                />
    <Scene key='sw'
                component={sw}
                title='star wars'

                />
    <Scene key='hp'
                component={hP}
                title='BTour'

                />
    <Scene key='bttf'
                component={bttf}
                title='Back to the future'

                />
    <Scene key='tM'
                component={tM}
                title='MAtrix'

                />
    <Scene key='iN'
                component={iN}
                title='Inception'

                />

       </Scene>
    </Router>
 )
     export default SceneManager;
```

and my Handlepage.js

```
import StarWars from './StarWars';
import BTTF from './BacktotheFuture';
import TM from './theMatrix';
import IN from './Inception';

export default class handlePage extends Component {
renderElement() {
  if(this.props.text ==1) {
      return <StarWars/>
  }
  if (this.props.text ==2) {
      return <BTTF/>
  }
  if (this.props.text ==3) {
    return <TM/>
  }
  if(this.props.text == 4) {
    return <IN/>
  }
  return null;
}
render(){
  return(
    this.renderElement()
  )
}
};
```

NOW MY PROBLEM:
I want to use the Scene what I have defined in my Router class. For example when I press the first button in the Home Screen then "Star Wars" will be open but not the Component what I write in the route class.

Can I take the Component Scene from Route.js to the HandlePage.js in the If-Statemant OR can I put the If Statemant in the Router class.

Right now only the script in the IF-Statemant will open.

Comment: Just use [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)  as I said before. If you already have a router wrap all scene, you could change scene to `Actions.sceneName()` like @Mahdi N answered, or just switch and return scene like my answer in your last question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think defining `handlePage` as class is necessary, you can just declare a function to navigate to your scene depending on `item.id`

Handlepage.js

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export const navigateByItemId = (id) => {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      Actions.jump('sw');
      break;
    case 2:
      Actions.jump('bttf');
      break;
    case 3:
      Actions.jump('tM');
      break;
    default:
      Actions.jump('iN');
  }
};
```

And in `App.js` you can call this utility function to decide where to navigate

```
import { navigateByItemId } from './Handlepage';

...

     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigateByItemId(item.id) }}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

You can delete handlePage declaration in your router:

```
    <Scene key='hp' //you can delete this code
                component={hP}
                title='BTour'
                />
```

Comment: When I make it like this, every button return the default value.

Comment: @Hasan try to console log id in `navigateByItemId`  function. check id type type if it's string then change cases to string (ex: `case '1':` ...)

Comment: ok, it was a String type. Now everything works fine. Thank you :)